# How to set up Filebeat and Metricbeat with Kibana the right way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, kibana, filebeat

We have our application with microservices on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

We want to use Filebeat and Metricbeat on the app servers and be able to visualize all the information in Kibana.

Our idea is to have Filebeat and Metricbeat on each App server (staging and production). The beats will ship data to a standalone EC2 instance with ElasticSearch + Kibana.

Are we going in the right direction? What improvements can we make?

[image]

Comment: That will certainly work. Make sure, however, to not mix the staging/prod indexes, so it's easier to keep the data tidy and separate for each environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going in the right direction, but. As @val said, do not mix indexes.
Also I would send everything to Logstash, and then to Elasticsearch.

Logstash normalises different schema. What does this mean? Simply put, Logstash allows you to put the data it gathers from your various systems into a single common format. This allows Elasticsearch/Kibana to make the most of your data. If your data was stored in a wide variety of different formats, it would not be possible for Elasticsearch and Kibana to use it effectively.

More thing to consider is the memory / storage you may need, will depend on how many docs you receive.

https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash